# Can anyone say is it possible to create hive external tables using Java

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am able to create internal tables but i am unable to create external tables hive. Can anyone suggest me whether is it possible or not to create hive external tables.
By doing r & d i came to know that by using CliDriver we can create but there i am unable to create.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/userdb","hiveuser","*****");
        System.out.println("connected");

        java.sql.Statement stmt =  connect.createStatement();


        /*stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE ezytrukdb");
        System.out.println("Database created successfully.");
        */
        String tableName = "SHIPPER";
        //ssstmt.executeQuery("drop table" +tableName);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE "+ tableName + " (S_ID INT, S_NAME VARCHAR(100), S_ADDR VARCHAR(100), S_CITY VARCHAR(40))");

        String showTable = "SHOW TABLES '"+ tableName + "'";
        System.out.println("Running: " +showTable);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(showTable);
        if(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }
        connect.close();
```

Comment: What's your code/command executed? What error are you getting?

Comment: yes I can say...:D

Comment: If u see above code it is working for creating internal tables in hive. But this is not working when i am giving CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in stmt. Let me know how to create to external table.

Answer (score 0):

no difference between hive cli and beeline or java via JDBC to hiveserver2. I think the same sql will get the same result.

Comment: yeah...but my question was is it possible to create hive external table using java.

Comment: of course it is possible to create hive external table using java. I don't find anything abnormal in your create table code.  I run your code, create external table seems ok, but show tables has syntax error.